# How to show SweetAlert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

How can I show SweetAlert in this JavaScript code?

```
function removeReg(del_reg) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete? \n the reg name : " + del_reg)) {
    // Code goes here
  }
}
```

I just want to call SweetAlert in the `if` condition, i.e. in SweetAlert, I need to show the message `"Are you sure you want to delete?"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [**`swal()` with your custom options**](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-options) in the `removeReg(del_reg)` function and use the [**`Promise`**](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) returned by `swal()` to determine what is the user's choice:

- If the user clicked `YES`, the returned `value` will be `true`
- If the user clicked `NO` or pressed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the returned `value` will be `null`

```js
var button = document.getElementById('remBtn')

function removeReg(del_reg) {
  swal({
      text: "Are you sure you want to delete? \n the reg name : " + del_reg,
      icon: "error",
      buttons: ['NO', 'YES'],
      dangerMode: true
    })
    .then(function(value) {
      console.log('returned value:', value);
    });
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked on button')
  removeReg('SomeCustomRegName');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="remBtn">Remove Registered Name</button>
```

[**More on the advanced examples of SweetAlert**](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)