# Use Javascript if function to display a SweetAlert popup

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I would like to display a [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples) popup if uploads are currently switched off, this is set by the `li` element having a class of "upload-off"

How can I incorporate an if Javascript condition to display the popup and just do nothing if the "upload-on" class if present of the `<li>`

I plan to use Vue on the page at a later date, so preferably need to use Javascript rather than jQuery (as I here of potential conflicts with Vue and jQuery)

```
<!-- There are two classes which toggle, upload-off and upload-on-->
<li class="uploadli upload-off">
    <p>Upload Off</p>
</li>

<input value="" id="myuploadbutton" type="file" name="Uploader" placeholder="Upload here">

<!-- Sweetalert Popup - Only display popup if uploads are currently disabled



function upload_check() {
swal({
    text: "Uploads are currently disabled, please apply here at http://www.example.com/apply",
    icon: "error",
    buttons: ['Apply Now'],
    dangerMode: true
    })
    .then(function(value) {
    console.log('returned value:', value);
    });
}

-->
```

OVERVIEW: User click on upload button, if the class "upload-off" is present on the `<li>` element we get a SweetAlert popup

Here is a similar SweetAlert issue

[How to show SweetAlert in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579801/how-to-show-sweetalert-in-javascript)

Comment: so look to see if the element exists, if it does not then call it.... Seems weird you do not disable it...

Comment: It's getting SweetAlert to display the info I am struggling with

Comment: well did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So check to see if the element exists

```js
document.querySelector("#myuploadbutton")
  .addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var li = document.querySelector('li.uploadli.upload-off');
    if (li) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      swal({
        text: "Uploads are currently disabled, please apply here at http://www.example.com/apply",
        icon: "error",
        buttons: ['cancel', 'Apply Now'],
        dangerMode: true
      }).then(function(value) {
        console.log('returned value:', value);
        if (value) {
          // window.location.href = "//www.example.com/apply"
        }
      });
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="uploadli upload-off">
    <p>Upload Off</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<input value="" id="myuploadbutton" type="file" name="Uploader" placeholder="Upload here">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add the if condition for `upload-off` check in the `click` event.

Delete line **event.returnValue = true;** if you want to do nothing on upload-on

```js
$("input[type=file]").on('click', function(event) {
  if (document.querySelector('li.uploadli.upload-off')) {
    swal({
        text: "Uploads are currently disabled, please apply here at http://www.example.com/apply",
        icon: "error",
        buttons: ['Apply Now'],
        dangerMode: true
      })
      .then(function(value) {
        console.log('returned value:', value);
      });
    event.preventDefault();
    //do something
  } else if (document.querySelector('li.uploadli.upload-on')) {
    swal({
        text: "Uploads are currently disabled, please apply here at http://www.example.com/apply",
        icon: "error",
        buttons: ['Apply Now'],
        dangerMode: true
      })
      .then(function(value) {
        console.log('returned value:', value);
      });
    event.returnValue = true; //delete if you want to do nothing on upload-on
    //   alert("nothing is done");

  } else {
    alert("nothing");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<li class="uploadli upload-off">
  <p>Upload Off</p>
</li>

<input value="" id="myuploadbutton" type="file" name="Uploader" placeholder="Upload here">
```